# How to suppress errors/outputs from a TCL thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, error-handling, tcl, dev-null

I have created a thread :

```
set t1 [thread::create]
thread::send $t1 {
    proc myProc {command args} {
        exec {*}[auto_execok $command] {*}$args >& /dev/null
    }
}
```

And then tried to send an asynchronous command :

```
thread::send -async $t1 [list myProc <command args>]
```

But the error/output from the command is getting displayed in output.
How to hide the errors/outputs from the command that is send to the async thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to `catch` the errors.

```
thread::send $t1 {
    proc myProc {command args} {
        catch {
            exec {*}[auto_execok $command] {*}$args >& /dev/null
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that this makes any problems *significantly* more difficult to debug! It's better if you can identify what errors you expect and just `try` to catch them, so unexpected errors are still things you see and have to handle.

```
thread::send $t1 {
    proc myProc {command args} {
        try {
            exec {*}[auto_execok $command] {*}$args >& /dev/null
        } trap CHILDSTATUS {} {
            # Ignore a non-zero exit?
        }
    }
}
```

For this specific case (which is very much I/O-bound from Tcl's perspective) you might be better off just adding `&` to the end of the `exec` call and not running in a separate thread. Can't really say for sure without knowing exactly what you're doing, but it is worth considering.

Comment: Thanks Donal ! catch worked.
I want to run a low priority job in a separate async thread, so that the main job will run unaffected.